# Django form field required on condition

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django model form where i want to make a form field required if some value is selected in another form field.

e.g 
if activity_name = 'Project Planned Activities' is selected in activity_name form field the project_id field should be required = true

I have added a form validator for this but its not working

```
class ActivityTrackerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    activity_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=activity.objects.all().order_by('activity_name'),
        label='', 
        empty_label="Select Activity", 
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            }
            )
        )
    project_id = forms.CharField(
        label='', 
        required=False, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "Project ID", 
            'class': 'form-control'
            }
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = activity_tracker
        fields = ['activity_name', 'project_id']


    def clean(self):
        activity = self.cleaned_data.get('activity_name')
        if re.search("^Project.*Activities$", str(activity)):
            self.fields['project_id'].required = True
```

Tried using the form validator

if activity_name = 'Project Planned Activities' is selected in activity_name form field the project_id field should be required = true

Comment: your code is not readable at all

Comment: @NancyMooree is it fine now

Comment: yes. its okay now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was first in my Validator itself  and in my view. i was not passing the current form to the template instead i was passing the new form eveytime to my template.

Corerct Form Validator

```
class ActivityTrackerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(label='', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
                           "placeholder": "Select Date", 'id': 'datepicker', 'class': 'form-control w-100', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    activity_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=activity.objects.all().order_by(
        'activity_name'), label='', empty_label="Select Activity", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    system_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=system.objects.all().order_by('system_name'), label='', empty_label="Select System", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    client_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=client.objects.all().order_by(
        'client_name'), label='',  empty_label="Select Client", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    hour_choice = [('', 'Choose Hours'), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2),(3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8)]
    hours = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=hour_choice, widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    min_choice = [('', 'Choose Mins'), (0, 0), (15, 15), (30, 30), (45, 45)]
    mins = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=min_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    no_of_records = forms.IntegerField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Enter no. of Records", 'class': 'form-control w-100', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    project_id = forms.CharField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Project ID", 'class': 'form-control w-100'}))
    user_comments = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Enter Your Comments Here...",
                'rows': 6,
                'class': 'form-control w-100',
                'autocomplete': 'off'
            }
        )
    )


    class Meta:
        model = activity_tracker
        fields = ['date', 'activity_name', 'system_name', 'client_name',
                  'hours', 'mins', 'no_of_records', 'project_id', 'user_comments']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ActivityTrackerModelForm, self).clean()
        activity = cleaned_data.get('activity_name')
        project_1 = cleaned_data.get('project_id')
        if re.search("^Project.*Activities$", str(activity)) and project_1 == "":
            self.add_error('project_id', "Please Add Project ID")
        return cleaned_data
```

Corrrect View

```
def MyTask(request):
    form = ActivityTrackerModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActivityTrackerModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user_name = request.user
            obj.approver = tascaty_user.objects.get(
                username=request.user).approver
            if request.user.is_team_lead:
                obj.status = activity_status.objects.get(pk=3)
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'New Entry Created')
            return redirect('mytask')

    queryset1_PA = activity_tracker.objects.filter(
        user_name=request.user).filter(status__in=[1, 2, 4]).order_by('-id')
    queryset1_AP = activity_tracker.objects.filter(
        user_name=request.user).filter(status=3).order_by('-date')
    paginator_RA = Paginator(queryset1_AP, 10)
    paginator_PA = Paginator(queryset1_PA, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    context = {
        'title': 'TasCaty|My Task',
        'activity_form': form,
        'post_page_RA': paginator_RA.get_page(page),
        'post_page_PA': paginator_PA.get_page(page),
    }
    return render(request, "tascaty/mytask.html", context)
```